# Классы Bootstrap - подскажите где найти весь список?

Tags: bootstrap

В официальной документации нет описания ВСЕХ классов: http://getbootstrap.com/
navbar-default,
navbar-header,
navbar-toggle
и т.д.

Comment: https://bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-3-css-classes-index/

Comment: @ L. Vadim - Огромное спасибо за помощь! То, что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Что Вы имеете в виду под "описанием всех классов"?

Элементы, которые Вы указали - находятся в [этой](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) части документации.

Список элементов UI можно посмотреть, например, [здесь](http://bootswatch.com/default/).

**UPD:** @L. Vadim [шарит](https://bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-3-css-classes-index/).

Comment: bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-3-css-classes-inde‌​x  - именно вот это и имелось в виду - весь список применяемых классов с описанием.   http://getbootstrap.com/ - здесь нет описания - просто применение.

Comment: Да, прояснилось.